# Esconder linha de título do TabLayout

Tags: android

Meu aplicativo tem uma versão free, com propaganda e apenas um tipo de cálculo, enquanto o pago não tem propaganda e hoje tem dois cálculos e ainda incluirei um outro. O que eu gostaria de saber é se é possível esconder a linha de título das abas na versão gratuita, já que é uma opção só. Pesquisei muito e não encontrei solução. Obrigado

Comment: A versão paga e a free são duas apps diferentes? Se sim, tenta implementar de forma diferente, não percebi la muito bem, mas se tens apenas uma aba podes usar apenas um Fragment

Comment: É uma app só, mas utilizando Flavor eu gero um package diferente para cada caso, ou seja, basta eu testar a variável do BuildConfig para saber se estou na "free" ou na "paga". Qual comando utilizo para que a barra de títulos do TabLayout não apareça na free, mantendo a aba visível? É o ideal, pois tenho muitos campos na tela e ganharia este espaço se conseguir tirar